# Average-case analysis of linear search

Tags: summation, algorithms

For linear search algorithm, if $x$ is the $ith$ term, two comparisons will be used at each of the $i$ steps of the loop, and one outside the loop, so a total of $2i+1$ comparisons are used, which is fine.

The average number of comparisons used equals:

$$\frac{3+5+7+\textit{...}+(2n+1)}{n} = \frac{2(1+2+3+4+\textit{...}+n)+n}{n}$$

**Question**: How we got that $\frac{3+5+7+\textit{...}+(2n+1)}{n}$ equals $\frac{2(1+2+3+4+\textit{...}+n)+n}{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
3 + 5+7 + \ldots (2n+1)
 = \sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1)
 = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^n 1
 = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n k + n
$$

In simpler words, there are exactly $n$ terms in your sum, so if you subtract one from each of them, you get $n$. Then,
$$
3+5+\ldots+(2n+1)
 = [2+4+\ldots +2n] + n
 = 2[1 + 2 + \ldots + n] + n
$$